# Heating system zone is too hot

Tags: heating

One of the 4th zones on my heating systems is getting too hot true the return line making the room very hot and enableling the thermostat to do the job.

See the pics, hope this is enough, also 4 taco circulators

[image][image]

Comment: Can some one share me some advices?

Comment: What type of heating system do you have?